# Change color of active accordion column

Tags: css, html

I have created a FAQ-accordion and am currently trying to style it.

I am stuck with one thing: I am not getting the active tab to change the color once clicked.

I have tried it with a:hover but I think I might need to use a javascript for this?

You can see the accordion [here](https://www.urban-zweirad.de/spray-bike-faq)

Appreciate your help a lot!

Mark

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
.faq-panel-title a:focus {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: tried this but unfortunately didn't change a thing. it seems there is some problem with the hover color. i can't find the class thats setting the white color.

Comment: found it, i have edited my answer to show you what it should be

Answer (score 0):

if you want, you can use something like this

```
.faq-panel-title a:not(.collapsed) {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: how can I inactive the .collapsed background on the first load?